# QVariant deserialization gives invalid value

Tags: c++, qt, serialization

I have the following class I want to serialize and deserialize:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QVariant>

/**
 * @brief   The type used to store the \ref CComPacket::Cmd enum
 */
using CmdType = quint8;

/**
 * @brief   A smart container for the TCP packets
 */
class CComPacket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    /**
     * @brief   Provides the command information for the packet (tells how
     *          the data is supposed to be parsed).
     */
    enum class Cmd: CmdType
    {
        Invalid,
        ReadName,
        GiveName,
    };

    explicit CComPacket(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    /**
     * @brief   The ostream (<<) overloading
     * @param   out: The data stream to which the \p cpp class is going to
     *          be serialized.
     * @param   ccp: the class to be serialized into the \p out.
     * @return  reference to \p out.
     */
    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const CComPacket& ccp)
    {
        out << static_cast<CmdType>(ccp.m_cmd) << ccp.m_data;
        return out;
    }

    /**
     * @brief   The istream (>>) overloading
     * @param   in: The serialized data that will be deserialized to the \p cpp
     * @param   ccp: deserialized data goes here.
     * @return  The \p in reference.
     */
    friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, CComPacket& ccp)
    {
        CmdType tmp;
        in >> tmp >> ccp.m_data;
        ccp.m_cmd = static_cast<Cmd>(tmp);

        return in;
    }

    /**
     * @brief   The parsing command
     */
    Cmd m_cmd = Cmd::Invalid;

    /**
     * @brief   The data to be parsed
     */
    QVariant m_data;

};
```

I am trying to test this with this code:

```
CComPacket tmp;
tmp.m_cmd = CComPacket::Cmd::GiveName;
tmp.m_data = 5.112233;

QDataStream str;
str << tmp;

CComPacket tmp2;
str >> tmp2;
```

When debugging I see that the `m_cmd` member of `tmp2` is deserialized correctly but the `m_data` object is still invalid. From the documentation I understand that `QVariant` support serialization by default. What am I missing here?

Comment: in your test code you have QDataStream str operating on no device so it can't work. Is it just an oversight in this example or is it the real code?

Comment: It was the actual code. I have forgot to provide the actual buffer for the stream, as I have mwntioned in my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work, I had to incorporate the `QByteArray` that had to be used as the parameter for the `QDataStream`, since a phisical container was needed already. I planned on serializing the data to bytes anyways in the later step, so this just made everything easier. I added the following member functions:

```
QByteArray serialize();
static CComPacket deserialize(QByteArray& ba);

QByteArray CComPacket::serialize()
{
    QByteArray ba;
    QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    ds << *this;
    return ba;
}

CComPacket CComPacket::deserialize(QByteArray& ba)
{
    QDataStream ds(&ba, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    CComPacket cp;

    ds >> cp;
    return cp;
}
```

And this test code now works correctly (`tmp` is the same as `tmp2`):

```
CComPacket tmp;
tmp.m_cmd = CComPacket::Cmd::GiveName;
tmp.m_data = 5.112233;

QByteArray ba = tmp.serialize();
CComPacket tmp2 = CComPacket::deserialize(ba);
```